# Execute function on submit if form is validated

Tags: javascript, jquery

Relative beginner at JS, wanting to run a button animation function when the submit button is pressed, but only if the form is validated.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
...
<button class="btn" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");
const errorElement = document.getElementById("error");
const successMsg = document.getElementById("success-msg");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

const validate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (name.value.length < 3) {
    errorElement.innerHTML =
      "Your name should be at least three characters long.";
    return false;
  }

  ... /*various other rules for form fields */

  if (message.value.length < 15) {
    errorElement.innerHTML = "Please write a longer message.";
    return false;
  }

  errorElement.innerHTML = "";
  successMsg.innerHTML =
    "Thank you! I will get back to you as soon as possible.";

  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function () {
    successMsg.innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
  }, 6000);

  return true;
};

const emailIsValid = (email) => {
  return /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email);
};

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validate);

// Event listeners

/* $('.btn').on('click', toggleBtn); */

/* THE ANIMATION TRIGGERED BY CLASS CHANGE */
function toggleBtn() {
  alert("working");
  btn = this;
  btn.classList.add("is-active");
  setTimeout(function () {
    btn.classList.remove("is-active");
  }, 2500);
}
```

Have tried various 'if' statements and combinations, but can't quite get there!

Any help very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `submit` *event* of the form and cancel it. After you're done with validation and animation, you can `form.submit()` to submit, this time for real.

```js
const contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("dont-name-submit");

function validate(form) {
  var input = form.querySelector("[name=tetris]");
  if (!input.value) {
    input.classList.add("invalid");
    return false;
  }
  input.classList.remove("invalid");
  return true;
}

contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  // do validation
  if (!validate(contactForm)) {
    return;
  }

  // do animation
  submitBtn.classList.add("is-active");
  setTimeout(function() {
    submitBtn.classList.remove("is-active");

    actual_submit();
  }, 2500);

})


function actual_submit() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'https://matt-rudd.com/message.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function() {
      alert('form was submitted');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.btn {
  transition: 2s;
  transform: scale(1)
}

.is-active {
  transform: scale(2)
}

.invalid {
  background: rgba(255, 128, 128, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
  try submitting this required field empty:<br>
  <input name="tetris">
  <br>
  <input class="btn" type="submit" id="dont-name-submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks - still having an issue with my errors not working - down to this toublesome line 89: 

`submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validate);`

Code section: 

`contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

https://codepen.io/matt-rudd/pen/LYdjQrN


  // do validation
/* ISSUE IS WITH THIS NEXT LINE - not working! */ submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validate);
  // do animation
  btn.classList.add("is-active");
  setTimeout(function () {
    btn.classList.remove("is-active");
  }, 2500);
  // then submit
})
/// AJAX FOR PHP FORM SEND`

Comment: Full code: https://codepen.io/matt-rudd/pen/LYdjQrN

Comment: You had 2 event handlers for `submit`. I modified my example a bit hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried those amendments but I'm still not able to get my own validation messaging live... just the generic pop-ups (not sure where they come from - perhaps hard-coded into the browser on detection of form element?)

I know live links are likely frowned upon here but would appreciate you taking a look to see if you can spot any glaring errors?  

https://codepen.io/matt-rudd/pen/abYyVbN

Spent hours trying various options so thanks a ton for this help!

Comment: still baffled why submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validate); prevents the reset of my code from running?

When this line is commented out, code below it runs and the email sends.

Comment: I got a "Your message has been sent" when I checked it. You are not supposed to validate using `confirm()` but using your own logic. But since fields are marked as `required` you don't have to validate at all. So remove the `confirm` section.

Comment: Hey, thanks - but removing the confirm section leaves me with the same issue - the emails send ok but I get the default required messages (white box popups) instead of the custom text messages flashing up below the button as desired.

It's either include line 105 and the error/success messaging works but the submit animation and email send doesn't fire - or comment out and the submit button and email send works but not the custom error messaging.

Hopeful there's a way to get all three elements working together - just not sure how to code that.

Comment: The default required messages appear if you add `required` to the inputs. Otherwise you should apply your own logic for validating. If validation fails, you should `return` and not continue to `actual_submit()`

Comment: Ah I see. Have removed the 'required's.

I've reached the limit of my JS knowledge so far, when it comes to the validation bit though.

I think I'm fairly close to understanding this!

The custom validation code beginning 'const validate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();' (line 56) ends in return: true.

Then 'submitBtn.addEventListener("click", validate);' runs the validation code.

What I need to do is figure out how to run the rest of the code (button animation and email send) if that 'validate' returns 'true'.

Comment: I think what's throwing me here is this portion: `const validate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();`

I'm more familiar with standard `function ...() {`

Here's the pen again if you are able to spare a few more minutes unpacking this for me!

https://codepen.io/matt-rudd/pen/RwMxRwa

Comment: I have updated the snippet here. See if it makes more sense.

Comment: WONDERFUL! Thank you - it was the simple syntax of the validation if statement I wasn't familiar with.

i see how you converted it into a more straight forward function - the only casualty of this is I then lose the form reset after submission.

So I need to work out how and where to add this back in:

`setTimeout(function () {
    successMsg.innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('cf').reset();
    
  }, 6000);`

Huge thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 0):

Put `required` in the inputs you want to be validated. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

```js
testForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  testForm.classList.add('expanded')
})
```

```css
form {
  transition: 600ms ease-out;
}

form.expanded {
  transform: translateX(50px)
}
```

```html
<form id="testForm">
   <input required type="text"><button>submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks loads! That got my animation working. 

So nearly there... The only problem I have now is that broke my custom error messages that appear in text below the button (my preferred way of displaying 'required').

Perhaps a Codepen best to illustrate?

https://codepen.io/matt-rudd/pen/eYMEJQj

Seems to be a conflict with the const on line 7 and the class/id of the button element?

Would be great to get both the required text notices and button animation on validation working together if poss!

Comment: @MattRudd  Ahh, in that case, then the other answer is better suited for that application. The key is to stop execting the submit event handler (`return`) when your validate function returns false

Comment: ok thanks loads for your help.